# Rename files into sequential order when some are missing

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of jpg files in a folder named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 4.jpg, 5.jpg, 8.jpg, 9.jpg and want to rename them to remove the gaps in the sequential order but keep them in the same order.

I've tried:

```
REORDER=1
for f in *.jpg
do
  printf "Moving "$f"\n"
  mv -n "$f" "$(date -r "$f" +"$REORDER").jpg"
  printf "Moved to "$REORDER"\n"
  ((REORDER++))
done
```

But that seems to misbehave and start doing odd things like looping around and renaming 1.jpg again!

Is there a better way to do this without loosing the original order of the files?

Comment: You don't check if the current file has to be moved or not. You just move *every* file.

Comment: "rename them to remove the gaps in the sequential order but keep them in the same order." What would be the result you have in mind: `1.jpg` up to `6.jpg`? What is the logic for 'removing gaps'?

Comment: The "$(date -r "$f" +"$REORDER").jpg" part is my attempt at keeping them in order by time created.

Comment: In this example, I want to keep 1.jpg and 2.jpg then rename 4.jpg to 3.jpg, rename 5.jpg to 4.jpg, rename 8.jpg to 5.jpg and 9.jpg to 6.jpg. I need to end up with a bunch of sequential filenames without gaps and without disturbing the order.

Comment: Your main problem is that *.jpg is not sorted numeric, you will process `1.jpg, 10.jpg 3.jpg 4.jpg` in this order (not 10.jpg last).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your filenames contain embedded spaces, don't use this answer. Otherwise it will work fine.

I'm not sure what the point of the call to `date` is in your script, but this script works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

REORDER=1

find . -name '*.jpg' -printf "%f\n" | sort -n | while read f
do
        DEST="$REORDER.jpg"
        if [ "$DEST" != "$f" ]
        then
                mv "$f" "$DEST"
        fi
        ((REORDER++))
done
```

Not that you have to use `find` because you need to sort the output numerically. If you don't do this, `7.jpg` will be processed after `79.jpg` is.

Comment: So .. er .. [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [quote your variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#When_Should_You_Quote.3F), especially since you're processing `*.jpg`.

Comment: Got it .. er .. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it's perfect. I was missing the sorting part! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can sort all files numeric and then read one by one and rename:

```
declare -i index=1
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    mv "$file" "$index.jpg"
    index=index+1
done< <(find -type f -printf '%f\0' | sort -zn)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the following likely fails if you have newlines in your filenames.

```
a=( *.jpg ) IFS=$'\n' a=( $(sort -n <<<"${a[*]}") )
for i in "${!a[@]}"; do mv -v "${a[$i]}" "$((i+1)).jpg"; done
```

This first builds and sorts an array of your files.
Then it walks through that array (whose first index is zero) and renames each file to include the index plus one.

It relies on the fact that bash non-associative arrays maintain index order.